# Match a string but not a blank space using HTML5 input pattern

Tags: html, validation

I'm using the HTML5 `pattern` attribute in an `<input>` to return a match for a specific string: `'felfogtam'`

My current markup is:

```
<input type="text" class="input input-small" pattern="felfogtam">
```

It does work, but the input is still valid if the field is empty. How can I change the regular expression to not allow a blank field?

Comment: If you post a working example of your code to a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) it will help with finding a solution.

Comment: @ZackT. I'm aware that jsFiddle exists, and I was sure that this code is simple enought to not use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the [`required`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-required-attribute) attribute

```
<input type="text" class="input input-small" pattern="felfogtam" required>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bJU2D/